# How to use terraform import with passed-in variables?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm learning terraform, and want to setup an AWS infrastructure using the tool.

We have 3 AWS environments, sandbox, staging, and production, and have existing infrastructure to support these environments. For example, we have 3 separate VPCs for each environment.

I want to use `terraform import` to import the states of these resources, based on the environment I'm trying to setup. So I essentially want to do this, though I know this is not syntactically correct, but you get the idea.

```
$ terraform import aws_vpc.my_vpc -var 'environment=sandbox'
```

I therefore have my module setup like this

```
vpc/main.tf
-----------
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}
resource "aws_vpc" "my_vpc" {
  cidr_block = ""
}

vpc/variables.tf
----------------
variable "environment" {
  type map = map(string)
  default {
    sandbox    = "vpc-1234"
    staging    = "vpc-2345"
    production = "vpc-3456"
  }
}
```

So this means I essentially want to do

```
$ terraform import aws_vpc.my_vpc vpc-1234
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think the root cause here is that workspaces are not m=being mapped to environments. That may be the problem based on information provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for information

> The terraform import command is used to import existing
>   infrastructure.
>
> The command currently can only import one resource at a time. This
>   means you can't yet point Terraform import to an entire collection of
>   resources such as an AWS VPC and import all of it. This workflow will
>   be improved in a future version of Terraform [import usage](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/usage.html).

The one you are passing these will be considered as input variables for sub-sequent modules, not the get value from Environment variables file but to set value for variables.

> Input variables serve as parameters for a Terraform module, allowing
>   aspects of the module to be customized without altering the module's
>   own source code, and allowing modules to be shared between different
>   configurations. [configuration variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html)

**Import syantax:**

```
terraform import aws_instance.example i-abcd1234
```

> This command locates the AWS instance with ID i-abcd1234 and attaches
>   its existing settings, as described by the EC2 API, to the name
>   aws_instance.example in the Terraform state.

So the way around to deal with import using variables can be System environment variables,
As ec2 can be imported, so the example is based on importing instance using the variable.

**instance.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  region              = "us-west-2"
  profile             = "test"
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami                         = "ami-0f2176987ee50226e"
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  associate_public_ip_address = false
  subnet_id                   = "subnet-example"
  vpc_security_group_ids      = ["sg-example"]
  key_name                    = "mytest-ec2key"
  tags = {
    Name = "Test EC2 Instance"
  }
}
```

To pass variables to the above script you can System environment variable.

```
 export stage_instance=i-abcexample && terraform import aws_instance.ec2 $stage_instance
```

or you can also try

```
export stage_instance=abc && export prod_instance=abc
```

then try to import

```
terraform import aws_instance.ec2 $stage_instance
```

[image]

Comment: This means I have to program `stage_instance` and `prod_instance` outside of terraform (.bashrc file). I was hoping there would be a pure terraform solution.

Comment: yes exactly, put them in bashrc or do it like i posted in answer

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue and figured out that the order is important. 
This command works:

```
$ terraform import -var 'environment=sandbox' aws_vpc.my_vpc vpc-1234
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had a VM (an associated Disk, NIC) moved to another resource group and I used below command to import the resources into the state file:

- Format:

  `terraform import -var-file='/path/to/my.tfvars' '<local reference name>' "<resource ID>"`
- Example:

  ```
  terraform import -var-file='../tfvars/prod.tfvars' 'module.MySystem.azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.windsvm["dsvm0003"]' "/subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/resourceGroups/myRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/DSVM0003"
  ```

Note:

1. The order of the arguments matter for `terraform import`! Wrong order might throw an error like: `The import command expects two arguments`.
2. Use the single quotes around the local resource reference.